# Send HTTPService Request in flex 3 with '-' in the URl Paramerters to get Google Feeds

Tags: url, flex3, request, httpservice

I am developing application in flex 3 which interacts with the Google feeds to produce my results. The URL to which i want to send request is something like this

> http://books.google.com/books/feeds/volumes?q=football+-soccer&start-index=11&max-results=10

Now i can send and receive results with q parameter, but in the next two parameters has a '-' (start-index and max-results). I am using HTTPService to send the requeset like this.

> SearchService.url = "http://books.google.com/books/feeds/volumes";
>
> SearchService.method = "GET";
>
> SearchService.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Here SearchService is the HTTPService

> var params:Object = new Object();
>
> params.q = searchText;
>
> params.start-index = 11;
>
> params.max-results = 100;
>
> service.SearchService.send(params);

Now my flex IDE throws me a error stating 'Cannot assign a non-reference value'. Only if i send the request with this parameters, i could put pagination in my application. So how can i send HTTPService request with '-' in the URL parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
var params:Object = new Object();
params["q"] = searchText;
params["start-index"] = 11;
params["max-results"] = 100;
service.SearchService.send(params);
```

Validated and tested to work properly! :)